# Nothing gets printed in the doc using PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

I am using PHPWord to download docx files in php. But nothing gets printed in the file if I try to download it. But the contents get displayed in the file which gets saved on the server. Below is the code which I have used. Can anyone please tell me what the issue is.

```
<?php
include "../includes/config.inc.php";
include '../PHPWord.php';

// Create a new PHPWord Object
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

// Every element you want to append to the word document is placed in a section. So you need a section:
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();

$section->addText('CANDIDATES DETAILS');

$filename='test';

$file=$filename.'.docx';
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('/form_doc/'.$filename.'.docx');


//download the file
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Neha

Comment: before the **header** you should check `if(file_exists($file)){//your code }` and if not found then it would be your **file path** problem. and remember that `header` needs **full document path**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should set **path** to file to `readfile()` and `filesize()` functions:

```
$file = $filename.'.docx';
$filepath = '/form_doc/' . $file;
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save($filepath);

//download the file
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
readfile($filepath);
```